# git pull while ssh into remote shows no prompts for username/password

Tags: bash, git, ssh

I am trying to write a script that ssh into a remote location and then performs a `git pull` as follows

```sh
ssh url@location << EOF
--other commands--
git pull
--other commands--
EOF
```

However whenever I run the script it fails the username/password prompt, which it never shows on the terminal. I would actually in this case *prefer* having to enter my credentials rather than making adjustments to the remote machine, does anyone know how to get the prompts to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need here-doc, you can just [write the command as `ssh` argument](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

```
ssh url@location git pull
```

This doesn't allow `git` to ask for password because this is command line-only call, and `git` requires a terminal to ask for password. So you have to make `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-terminal:

```
ssh -t url@location git pull
```

If you have more than one command to run — pass them all in quotes:

```
ssh url@location "cd /path/to/repo && git pull && echo ok"
ssh -t url@location "cd /path/to/repo && git pull && echo ok"
```

Comment: I use a stdin here-doc because there are other commands I need to perform, like cd'ing to the repository. I can add this to the question

Comment: @wjmccann I updated the answer for multiple commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your git user on the remote machine with a personal access token, in order to not get the username/password prompt.

Comment: In the question body I state that I do not want to configure so that the prompt does not happen, I just want to make it so the prompt appears in my terminal